# WHERE clause on null in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables which, to simplify, look like this:

**TheFiles**

```
FileID | UserID
 23    |   342
 53    |   352
```

**TheData**

```
UserID |  DateCreated
  352  |    7/22/2014
  245  |    7/25/2014  
  589  |    7/28/2014
```

I'm looking to return a nullable int that represents the latest `UserID` from the table `TheData` that's not in the table `TheFiles`. So for example, with this sample data, the return value would be 589 because it's the latest entry in TheData and it's not in the table TheFiles.

I'm having some trouble on the `where` when there's no data. This is what I have:

```
var TheNullableInt = (from d in MyDC.TheData
                      where d.UserID doesn't exist in MyDC.TheFiles
                      orderby d.DateCreated descending
                      select d.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm using linq-to-SQL. How can I do the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from d in MyDC.TheData
     where  !MyDC.TheFiles.Any(tf=>tf.UserID == d.UserID)
```

or do a `join`

```
from d in MyDC.TheData
join tf in MyDC.TheFiles on tf.UserID equals tf.UserID into j
from x in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where x == null
select.....
```

Comment: @frenchie, not me, there are too many downvoters out there! I just upvoted it!

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastest = MyDC.TheData.Where(d => !MyDC.TheFiles.Any(f => f.UserID == d.UserID))
                          .OrderByDescending()
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if you *really* want to use LINQ

```
var latest = (from d in MyDC.TheData
              where !MyDC.TheFiles.Any(f => f.UserID == d.UserID)
              orderby d.DateCreated descending
              select d
             ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Great answer; ADNet beat you by just 1 min. Upvoted nonetheless.

Comment: @frenchie I had actually answered first but I misread the question initially. I thought you *had* a where clause but you just wanted to handle scenarios where there was no records....my edit meant I re-posted late.